# How to get the of values spit out by count() in php

Tags: php

So I am counting the values of several arrays, which are nested in a major array (don't know if this bit matters, but just going to throw that out there anyways).

```
$counter = 0;
forEach($decodedData as $key => $value) {
    $counter = count($value);

}
echo $counter."\n";
```

this is is outputting something like this: 4 3 1 7 8 45 235 8 54 5

my question is, is there anyway I can get the sum of these numbers?

Okay, so some people are asking I should post the array which is $decodedData. it looks something like this. I want to count the number of elements in each "person", and make a total.

```
Array
(
[person1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

    )

[person2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

    )

)
Array
(
[person3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

    )

[person4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

    )

[person5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sent] => data
                [received] => data
            )

    )
```

Comment: `$counter += count($value);`

Comment: Have you tried adding them together?

Comment: `$sum = array_sum(array_map('array_count_values', $decodedData));`

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I tried $counter += count($value) it is outputting wonky stuff like: 12 45 35 75, I'm trying to get whole sum of number

Comment: @Salman Probably because your `echo` statement is within the `forEach` loop. Place it outside the loop and then it'll only return the final sum as oppose to the sum after each iteration of the loop...

Comment: @War10ck you're right, but it is narrowed down, but still outputting 9 9 1 18 166 2355 70 99 2 6 5 63 6 60 3 132 1669 426 3 34 21 25983 260 116 weird numbers like that

Comment: use  `array_sum($decodedData);` check my answer.

Comment: @MarkBaker please see my edited question

Comment: @War10ck please see my edited question

Comment: Based on what you are saying this is outputting, are you **sure** you are not `echo`ing the counter inside the loop? It certainly seems like you must be.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yup, not inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($decodedData as $key => $value) {
    $counter += count($value);
}
echo "Total: ".$counter;
```

this will get you total

**EDIT**
I've used this `array` -- as you specified.

```
$decodedData = array
(
    "Person1" => array(array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data")),
    "Person2" => array(array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data")),
    "Person3" => array(array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data")),
    "Person4" => array(array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"), array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data")),
    "Person5" => array(array("sent" => "data", "received" => "data"))
);
```

check **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/sUlG0L)** now. **`Total: 12`**

Comment: I'm getting a weird response back like this though, Total: 9Total: 9Total: 1Total: 18Total: 166Total: 2355Total: 70Total: 99Total: 2Total: 6Total: 5Total: 63Total: 6Total: 60Total: 3Total: 134Total: 1672Total: 426Total: 3Total: 34Total: 21Total: 26045Total: 260Total: 116.     I just want teh one total

Comment: Hi Mubin, please see my edited question, I have posted teh array, it is a nested array. I don't know if that matters

Answer (score 0):

As just @MarkBaker said use something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($decodedData as $key => $value) {
    $counter += count($value);
}
echo $counter."\n";
```

Comment: I did so, but it is still outputting weird numbers 9 9 1 18 166 2355 70 99 2 6 5 63 6 60 3 132 1669 426 3 34 21 25983 260 116 like so. I want one whole number which will be the sum.

Comment: please see my edited question, I have posted teh context of teh array, which is probably why I'm getting weird numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) for that, i.e.:

```
$decodedData = array("a" => 5, "b" => 25, "c" => 4.9);
echo array_sum($decodedData);
//34.9
```

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/paQbgA

Comment: for some reason, I'm just getting 000000 back, when I do this, I should mention that there are nested arrays.

Comment: You should update your question with the array content.

Comment: I Pedro, I updated the question with the array content, please see the question again. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, Which key contains the value ?

Answer (score -1):

Very simple.... Just

```
$counter += count($value);
```

Comment: I did so, but it is still outputting weird numbers 9 9 1 18 166 2355 70 99 2 6 5 63 6 60 3 132 1669 426 3 34 21 25983 260 116 like so. I want one whole number which will be the sum.

Comment: Echo the variable outside the loop.... Ur problem is because its inside the loops.... So its printing every time

Comment: please see my edited question, I have posted the array, to get more context as to why I am not getting the total properly.